# Why is slug in publishing called a slug?

Tags: articles, titles, publishing

Slug as we know on the internet from the articles (example https://www.rollingstone.com/music/music-lists/best-albums-of-all-time-1062063/ 'music-lists/best-albums-of-all-time-1062063' being the slug in question) doesn't seem to be in any way related to an animal slug or a sluggish person. I wonder how it got the name to stick? Maybe it is an acronym for something ('**S**hortened **L**abel **U**nique **G**lobally' (just joking, I made this one up))?

Comment: Kindly attach the definition of the word in question.

Comment: _"The origin of the term slug derives from the days of hot-metal printing, when printers set type by hand in a small form called a stick. Later huge Linotype machines turned molten lead into casts of letters, lines, sentences and paragraphs. A line of lead in both eras was known as a slug."_ [Sourced from Wikipedia.] Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, one definition of slug is an identifying line. It may be related to a slug as a line of type set as a unit by a printer:

Merriam-Webster, definition 6 of slug:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slug

> b : a line of type cast as one piece

> c : a usually temporary type line serving to instruct or identify

Comment: 'Slug' seems to be, or have been, a general term for a small lump of lead. Bullets are sometimes referred to as 'slugs' as in "The slug missed my head by inches". Perhaps the printing term came from the shooting one.

Comment: @BoldBen I agree.

Comment: The piece of lead looks (like a bullet does) like a slug that you find in the garden.

Comment: @Michael Harvey - the physical resemblance does not seem to enter into the etymology. "Slug" is first recorded in the 15th century as referring to a large, slow, or lazy person or sluggard. In the 17th century, "slug" could be *anything* that was heavy **and/or** slow. It's use as a projectile referred to its relative weight. It was not until the early 18th century that the gastropod meaning was used in senses that indicated slowness.